# Show taps in iOS App Demo Video

Tags: ios, video, touch, record, demo

I am making demo videos of my iOS apps, some of which I made with XCode and others of which I made in Unity3D.  I plan to use the Elgato Game Capture HD to capture my demo videos but I am not sure how to show the "taps."  I found Touchpose, but when I changed the main.m as suggested by the instructions on the GitHub page I got error messages saying that QAppDelegate and QTouchposeApplication were undefined.  I added import "QTouchposeApplication" but got an error message suggesting I change QAppDelegate to AppDelegate.  When I did this the build failed.  When I left it as QAppDelegate, added QAppDelegate to the project and imported it into the main.m the error messages went away but the build still failed.  Am I doing something incorrectly?  I found no tutorials on Touchpose online and am confused.  Alternatively, is there some other easy solution, for example using the Elgato software or some other software or framework?  I also tried Reflector but my wifi is not fast enough to support good frame rates with it.  I am aware that I could use unity and "build for OSX" or in the case of XCode apps just screen record the simulator but I would prefer a single, foolproof solution for all of my apps.  Thanks!

Comment: This article has a number of different methods you can try: https://medium.com/whisperarts/how-to-record-and-show-screen-taps-gestures-in-app-previews-videos-for-ios-4f82d7b6fdc9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to demo on a simulator? If so, [Giphy Capture](https://giphy.com/apps/giphycapture) is a good solution. It has an option for showing taps in the settings.

Comment: I think this isn't as good as the accessibility option because you can always screen record the device with the accessibility option on.  The only downside I see is having potentially an indicator that you're screen-recording, for example in marketing materials.

Comment: But from the answer "You would have to superimpose multiple videos to make it so that only the tap shows and not the AssistiveTouch icon. Also, you can't scroll while using it."

Not being able to scroll is a pretty huge downside to me. Given, I haven't tested that method for myself so I don't know if that is true. But reading that made me not even want to try ha.

Comment: That's a fantastic point.  Especially the scrolling thing, which is a major drawback.

Answer (score 8):

One way is to use assistive touch and create your own touch. You can do this by going to Settings > General > Accessibility > AssistiveTouch, turn it on, then tap the thing that pops up, click Custom, then create your own touch. Then use that touch to show taps in a screen recording.

It's a bad solution, but I'll post it in case it fits your needs.

You would have to superimpose multiple videos to make it so that only the tap shows and not the AssistiveTouch icon. Also, you can't scroll while using it.

It's also explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JqjU0-4Cek

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer since my original, old answer used a broken link and didn't fully answer the question anyway.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, thank you! Also, I would like to update with my own solution since I figured out my own solution. I used Adobe Premier Pro and added in the taps as a picture overlay on the video (with something like 60% opacity, made it as a PNG in Photoshop)

Answer (score 2):

**Simulator Settings**

Option is present in Simulator Settings, under **Visual Indicators**
Refer image from --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBlQS.png

Answer (score 1):

If you can make your screen recording on iOS simulator, you can enable displaying taps with following code. Open your terminal and run it and restart your simulator.

```sh
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ShowSingleTouches 1
```

Comment: this is not visible in recording

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with Touchpose initially but figured out how to use it.  The issue is that you have to go to build phases and add the .m.  In regard to screen recording I am using the Elgato Game Capture HD.  My only problem is showing the dots on Unity 3D applications, which is something I am still working on.